# Solidity: chaining multiple functions

Tags: solidity, oracles

I have a contract that uses Oraclize to query some bits of data. Basically, I have the following three functions:

1. `getData()` - calls Oraclize contract to query data,
2. `__callback()` - called automatically by Oraclize, when data received.
3. `setData()` - function to get the queried value and do smth.

   ```
   contract functionChain is usingOraclize {

   string public globalKey;

   function getData() public payable {
       string memory query = 'json(http://QUERY_LINK)'; //returns string
       oraclize_query(0, "URL", query, 250000);
   }

   function setData(string text) internal {
       text = globalKey;
   }

   function __callback(bytes32 myId, string result) {
       if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) revert();

       setData(result);
   }
   }
   ```

The logic I have now is the following:
1. `getData()` is called
2. `__callback() { setData() }` - `setData()` is called by the `__callback()` function.

The problem is, that even though I can successfully query the data via Oraclize, `setData()` function is never being called. I am getting the logs of success only for the `getData()` function.

Is this even a legit way to use Oraclize query result in a third function? If not, what would be the best way of linking those functions together, so that `SetData()` is called after the `__callback()`?

Comment: Might be helpful to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: To begin with, you should change `text = globalKey` to `globalKey = text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import './usingOraclize.sol';

contract functionChain is usingOraclize {
    string public globalKey;
    mapping (bytes32 => bool) validIds;

    event LogResult(string result);
    event LogNewOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event LogFundsReceived(address sender, uint amount);

    constructor() public payable {
        OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(your oraclize address);
    }

    function() payable {
        LogFundsReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) public {
        require(validIds[myid]);
        require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
        globalKey = result;
        LogResult(result);
        delete validIds[myid];
    }

    function setData() public payable {
        if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
            LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent");
        }
        else {
            LogNewOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent");
            bytes32 queryId = oraclize_query("URL", "json(http://QUERY_LINK)");
            validIds[queryId] = true;
        }
    }
}
```